# Regular expression for a zipcode with 4 digits and 2 optional letters

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to check zip codes in JavaScript. The rule is 4 digits are mandatory and 2 letters at the end are optional. 1 space between the digits and the letters is also allowed.

Examples:

```
1019 //true
1019PZ //true
1019 PZ //true
1019P //false
(and anything else is false)
```

This is the regular expression I have so far. But in this regex the letters at the end are not optional but mandatory

```
var regex = /^[1-9][0-9]{3} ?(?!sa|sd|ss)[a-z]{2}$/i;
```

Any suggestions to make the letters at the end optional?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Group `[a-z]{2}` with a non-capturing group `(?:[a-z]{2})?` followed by `?` in order to make the group optional. In doing so, two letters will be optional and you can't have just a single letter.

```
^[1-9][0-9]{3} ?(?!sa|sd|ss)(?:[a-z]{2})?$
```

[**Example Here**](https://regex101.com/r/yV6vS3/1)

Answer (score 0):

For example You can try this one:

```
/^[1-9][0-9]{3} ?(?!sa|sd|ss)[a-z]{0,2}$/
```

Just add to a range a value of zero, which means that your letter can be present from zero to two times.

Answer (score 0):

The following works:

```
\d{4} ?[A-z]{2}?
```

- **\d{4}:** matches 4 mandatory digits
- **"space?**": matches one optional whitespace between digits and letters
- **[A-z]{2}?:** matches two optional letters

Comment: \s matches not only space character, also an tab character and so on. also there should be a group around [A-z]{2}

Comment: Testing on regexr.com, the group surrounding [A-z]{2}? doesn't seem to be mandatory. As for the \s, you're right and it is corrected.